# How to interpret a trained Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, graphs, graphical-model

I built my first decision tree, to predict if students will pass or not - the [data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/student+performance) - depending on 30 variables. Now I need to know how to read the decision tree, since many variables were strings and now are floats made me confused.

The 30 variables are:

```
school sex age address famsize Pstatus Medu Fedu Mjob Fjob reason guardian traveltime studytime failures schoolsup famsup paid activities nursery higher internet romantic famrel freetime goout Dalc Walc health absences
```

[image: The mentioned decision tree]

edit: to sum up I used the below code to generate this tree. How can i interpret it and understand the method the program is using, I want to understand every word and number written in the tree.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree 
import graphviz
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
d = pd.read_csv('student-por.csv', sep= ';')

d['pass'] = d.apply(lambda row: 1 if (row['G1']+ row['G2']+ row ['G3']) >= 35 else 0 , axis=1)
d = d.drop(['G1', 'G2','G3'], axis=1 )

#Converting string data to binary using one-hot encoding
d=pd.get_dummies(d, columns =['sex','activities','school', 'address', 'famsize','Pstatus','Mjob','Fjob','reason','guardian','schoolsup','famsup','paid','nursery','higher','internet','romantic'])
#shuffle rows
d = d.sample(frac=1)
#split traning and test
d_train = d[:500]
d_test = d[500:]

d_train_att = d_train.drop(['pass'], axis=1)
d_train_pass= d_train['pass']

d_test_att = d_test.drop(['pass'], axis=1)
d_test_pass= d_test['pass']

d_att = d.drop(['pass'], axis=1)
d_pass = d['pass']



t = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion ='entropy', max_depth = 3)
t= t.fit (d_train_att, d_train_pass)

#to export the tree
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(t,out_file = 'students-tree-3.dot', label ='all', impurity=False, proportion= True, feature_names=list(d_train_att), class_names=['fail', 'pass'], filled = True, rounded=True)
score =t.score (d_test_att, d_test_pass)
print (score)
scores = cross_val_score(t, d_att,d_pass, cv=5)


for maxx in range(1,20):
    t = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion ='entropy', max_depth =maxx)
    scores = cross_val_score (t, d_att, d_pass, cv=5)

    print ('Max depth %d Accuracy %0.2f (+/- %.2f )' % (maxx , scores.mean(), scores.std()*2 ))
```

If still not clear please tell me to clarify it further.

Comment: If this is a binary classification problem, Decision tree is classifying after the split into pass and fail. I am not sure what you mean by binary vs float. I can't find that in your figure.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake!! What I meant is **strings to floats**, as in variable 'Sex' the possible answers are 'Male' and 'Female'. So I had to do one-hot encoding to convert these strings into numbers.